# Regex positive lookahead for a character only after paired brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse SQL code using regex in Python.

I need an expression that would delimit group when it ends with end of string or comma but only if they follow after the matched brackets.

My current regexp matches second group only up to first occurrence of a comma, regardless of parentheses count:

`(?m)^\s*'?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)'?\s*=\s*((?s:.)*?)(?:\s*)(?=,|\Z)`

For example, in the string below:

```
COL1 = DEF1,
COL2 = DEF(TEST,
TEST2),
COL3 = FUN(1, 2),
```

I get:

```
0: DEF1
1: DEF(TEST
2: FUN(1
```

And I would like it to match:

```
0: DEF1
1: DEF(TEST,
TEST2)
2: FUN(1, 2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?sm)^\s*'?([\w-]+)'?\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=^\s*'?[\w-]+'?\s*=|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBqNsM/2)

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - DOTALL and MULTILINE options on
- `^` - start of a line
  -`\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `'?` - an optional `'`
- `([\w-]+)` - Group 1: one or more word or `-` chars
- `'?` - an optional `'`
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=^\s*'?[\w-]+'?\s*=|\Z)` - a positive lookahead requiring the end of string (`\Z`) or `^\s*'?[\w-]+'?\s*=` pattern immediately to the right of the current location.